# Problems with RunnableInterfaces in Java JDK-20

Tags: java, interface, java-20

I have problems to import an interface in Java. In intellj I can execute the code despite errors. When I do it with Java itself it does not work. Can you help me?

This is my interface.

```java
package jexample;

import java.util.Vector;

public interface RunnableInterface {
    public void run(Vector<String> args);
}
```

This is my MyCryptMain.java:

```java
package jexample;

import java.util.Vector;

public class MyCryptMain {

    static final String PROG_NAME = "MyCryptMain";
    static final String SCOPE = "jexample.";

    public static final String[][] MY_ARRAY = {
            {"-genkeys", SCOPE + "RunGenKeys"},
            {"-encrypt", SCOPE + "RunEncrypt"},
            {"-decrypt", SCOPE + "RunDecrypt"},
            {"-copy", SCOPE + "RunCopy"}
    };

    public static void usage() {
        String msg[] = {
                "Program '" + PROG_NAME + "'",
                "usage:",
                "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY[0][0]
                        + " [priv_keyfile] [pub_keyfile]",
                "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY[1][0]
                        + " [pub_keyfile] [ifile] [ofile] ",
                "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY[2][0]
                        + " [privkeyfile] [ifile] [ofile] ",
                "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY[3][0]
                        + " [dummyword] [ifile]  [ofile] ",
                ""
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; ++i) {
            System.err.println(msg[i]);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RunnableKeyValueFactory runnableKeyValueFactory = new RunnableKeyValueFactory(MY_ARRAY);

        int argSize = args.length;

        if (argSize <= 0) {
            usage();
        }

        String cmdKey = new String(args[0]);

        if (!runnableKeyValueFactory.containsKey(cmdKey)) {
            usage();
        }

        Vector<String> optArgVector = MyUtils.shiftArgs(args, 5);

        RunnableInterface myRun = runnableKeyValueFactory.getInstanceFromKey(cmdKey);

        myRun.run(optArgVector);

        System.out.println("Ende des Programms.");
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure:

```bash
C:.
\---jexample
        MyCryptMain.java
        MyUtils.java
        RunCopy.java
        RunDecrypt.java
        RunEncrypt.java
        RunGenKeys.java
        RunnableBase.java
        RunnableFactory.java
        RunnableInterface.java
        RunnableKeyValueFactory.java
```

As you can see, all files are in the right place and can be found.

```bash
javac .\MyCryptMain.java
.\MyCryptMain.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
RunnableKeyValueFactory runnableKeyValueFactory
^
symbol: class RunnableKeyValueFactory
location: class MyCryptMain
.\MyCryptMain.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
= new RunnableKeyValueFactory(MY_ARRAY);
^
symbol: class RunnableKeyValueFactory
location: class MyCryptMain
.\MyCryptMain.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
Vector<String> optArgVector = MyUtils.shiftArgs(args, 5);
^
symbol: variable MyUtils
location: class MyCryptMain
.\MyCryptMain.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
RunnableInterface myRun
^
symbol: class RunnableInterface
location: class MyCryptMain
4 errors
```

Nevertheless, java (javac) does not find the interface. Can you help me please?

Greetings Liffecs.

I expected java to find the interface and continue executing the program normally. In Intellj with OpenJDK 20 it also works without problems.

Comment: You should not go into the package directory. Run `javac` from the parent directory. Or, if you want to stay in that directory,. specify `-sourcepath ..`. Or just run `javac *.java`, if you are going to compile all files anyway. Btw, what’s the reason to use the ancient, outdated class `Vector` which has been superseded by `ArrayList` a quarter century ago?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the Java compiler from the wrong directory.

It seems you are running the `javac` command from within the `jexample` directory. This isn't made clear, but this can be deduced from the directory
structure and the fact that you are compiling the `Main` class using `javac .\Main.java`. You aslo say that the code compiles in IntelliJ. If this is the case then all of the classes must be the `jexample` package.

When the Java compiler starts compiling your `Main` class and needs to find the `RunnableKeyValueFactory` class in the `jexample` package, it looks for the file `RunnableKeyValueFactory.java` within the `jexample` subdirectory of the current directory. Because you are running `javac` from within the `jexample` directory, the Java compiler is looking for this class in

```
C:\-----\jexample\jexample\RunnableKeyValueFactory.java
```

I suspect this file does not exist. Hence the compiler cannot find your `RunnableKeyValueFactory` class.

Try changing to the parent directory and running `javac .\jexample\MyCryptMain.java`. Your code should compile from there, or if it doesn't, you should get different compiler errors.

Note that the Java compiler won't automatically detect that you are in a subdirectory whose name matches the package and automatically base its searches for classes from the parent directory.